# Ubuntu on Celeron D 326 2.53 GHz, 2 GB RAM and GMA 950

Tags: system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which version and derivate of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minmal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

Should I install Ubuntu or is the CPU too weak? It says the CPU is 64bit capable. So which version should I install? Should I use Unity 2d? Will Lubuntu be significantly faster on this PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu should run perfectly fine one that machine, but just to check burn a live CD and give it a go!

As for Unity 2d, have a see whether Unity 3d runs fast enough for you, 2GB of RAM and that CPU should handle it perfectly though.

32bit vs 64bit: Depends whether you plan on upgrading to 4GB+ of RAM really as this is the only real difference nowadays. I always but 64bit where I can just to be on the safe side and haven't run into problems so far.

Lubuntu will run slightly faster but not enough to compensate for what it lacks in comparison to Ubuntu's Unity in my opinion. If you don't believe me make a live CD/USB of that too and give that a go!

Hope this helps

Comment: I just got the PC and upgraded from 512 MB to 2 GB right away because I knew Ubuntu would be MUCH more fun with 2 GB. So you say I should use the 32bit version?

Comment: Well if you are not planning on upgrading your RAM in the future you might aswell, yes. Some (usually older and unsupported) programs don't have support for 64 bit operating systems, so running 32bit will ensure you have maximum compatibility. Although I always run 64 where I can so that if I ever do upgrade my RAM I don't have to reinstall. So it's completely up to you; either install 64bit to be on the safe side or if you don't mind reinstalling or are pretty sure you won't upgrade (I don't think you need to) go for 32 bit.